# .html is not a function with reqwest.js library

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

I am using the reqwest library to load a response and want to avoid jquery (it's too large here).

However, it seems that document.getElementById is not accepted for the .load call - if I change the "el" to jquery $("#content"), everything is fine. How should I rewrite the el.html(resp) part to handle this?

The example on reqwest uses the "qwery" library for selectors, but that's another 10kb I want to avoid. Thank you for any ideas!

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://private_path_to_s3/reqwest.min.js"></script>

<!--Content-->
<div id="content">Empty!</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
reqwest('http://localhost:3000/iframe?keyword=XXXXX', function (resp) {
  var el = document.getElementById("content");
  //Replace the content with the response
  el.html(resp);
  //rename the div to avoid refiring
  el.setAttribute("id", "ks-content-loaded");
})
</script>
```

Comment: can you add console.log(el); after   var el = document.getElementById("content");

Comment: so we can check if problem is in selector or in html function

Comment: Thanks for the console.log(el) trick, didn't know that yet. Helped me solve it with your suggestion below. Final code now: reqwest('http://localhost:3000/iframe?keyword=XXXXX', function (resp) {
  var el = document.getElementById("ks-content");
  //Replace the content with the response
  el.innerHTML = resp;
  //rename the div to avoid refiring
  el.setAttribute("id", "ks-content-loaded");
})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.html() is a jquery function.

To change html text in vanilla javascript you have to set 
**innerHTML** field

that's the code:

```
document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = new HTML
```

reference:

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_html.asp